# What does sleeping do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does sleeping in a bed in minecraft do anything else besides *turn night into morning instantly* to the game status, such as **advancing time** as if you had slept for X hours?

I'm curious because this could effect things such as crop growth, or breeding downtimes...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Sleeping does not:

- fast-forward time
- fast-forward any processes such as crops growing or furnaces melting/cooking

Sleeping does:

- change the time of day to the next morning, if every player sleeps at the same time
- set your spawn point so you will respawn next to that bed, after 5 seconds whether or not other players sleep

Comment: To clarify a bit also: The spawnpoint set is only done after 100 ticks (ideally 5 seconds on a non-lagging server) in bed even if sleep is not completed/time does not change.

This matters more on multiplayer were you could be prevented from completing sleep if other players do not also enter a bed.

Comment: I tried to improve the descriptions and incorporate EdGruberman's comment. Bit of a major edit; hope you don't mind.

Comment: Absolutely not :p

Comment: I think it should be added that if you sleep in a room with a light level lower then 7, a skeleton or zombie will spawn on you when you wake up, when this happens it also prevents the games time from changing

Answer (score 3):

Sleeping has one documented effect: Changing the time of night to the beginning of day. Furnaces burning when you hit the hay have not jumped ahead, potions are still brewing as if time had not passed, and as far as I know, crops continue to grow at their own rate.\

I am personally unsure about one other affect, and that is rain: some people claim that sleeping will shut off the rain, however I personally have never been able to get sure results.

Comment: I've had sleeping change the weather, too.

Comment: Re: Weather: Weather is randomly checked for a random possibility to change.  However weather is also checked each morning for a random possibility to change.  So sleeping and causing the morning to come quicker increases your odds greatly that the weather will change at that point.

Comment: There is a nice mod, [Somnia](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/162771-125-somnia-sspml/), which rapidly simulates the world while you sleep, so potions and furnaces and such will have progressed during the night.

Comment: I'd also add it doesn't make you hungry either

Comment: @EdGruberman Actually, when you sleep successfully the weather will *always* be cleared. Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/mindcrack/comments/v10rm/why_the_lack_of_sleep_on_the_mindcrack_server_may/c50ekhp?context=3